# UnicodeDecodeError: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I have a quick question about UnicodeDecodeError:invalid start byte.
I think somewhere in my text has non-UTF-8 Character, but location of error message is the starting point of reading a file, so I have no idea how to fix it.

If you have any suggestion, just let me know

Following is my error message returned from python.

```
for line in fi:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte
```

Following is my code:

```
for filename in os.listdir(readDir):
    filename = os.path.join(readDir, filename)
    for keyword in keywords:
        outFileName = os.path.join(sortDir, keyword)
        outFileName = outFileName+'.csv'

        with open(filename, 'r') as fi, open(outFileName, "a") as fo:
            for line in fi:
```

Comment: I think starting string has a non-UTF-8 character...Should I erase it?

Comment: Your file is actually UTF-8 or something else?

Comment: it's text file that consists of JSON format data

Comment: I mean it may include non UTF_8 format text because it is collected from Twitter

Comment: Is there a `€` in the text?

Comment: a lot of unicode characters are in the string:
\u8d85\u4fbf\u5229\u306a\u30d0\u30a4\u30c8\u30b7\u30d5\u30c8\u7ba1\u7406\u30a2\u30d7\u30ea\u304c\u767b\u5834\uff01\n\n\u50cd\u3044\u305f\u5408\u8a08\u6642\u9593\u3082\u308f\u304b\u308b\u3057\n\u30b3\u30ec\u306f\u4f7f\u3048\u308b\uff57\uff57\uff57

Comment: Json text is unicode text.  utf-8 is a bytes-encoding of unicode chars.  Utf-8 (more or less)  mandated for serialization of json text.  If a source sends bytes that do not decode properly, the fault is with the source.  It is equivalent to sending python code with a syntax error.  There is not much you can do except examining the text by eye (open in binary mode, read into one bytes object, and decode with `errors='replace'` rather than 'strict'.) and guess what the fix might be.  Otherwise put `try: except:` around the `with` statement to skip invalid files.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and after searching for a while what i did

```
import sys

#Set default encoder 
sys.setdefaultencoding("ISO-8859-1")

#Then convert string to UTF-8
yourString.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

I hope it will be useful to someone

Comment: There is no `setdefaultencoding`