# The Location of Directory and Unicode Error

Tags: python, unicode

This morning, I asked a question about unicode encoding error.
[UnicodeDecodeError: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28858321/unicodedecodeerror-invalid-start-byte?noredirect=1#comment46000242_28858321)

I got a error return which persists up to now. (error code is following)

```
for line in fi:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 313, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 3131: invalid start byte
```

So far I couldn't figure it out why this problem is happening, but I found something really interesting.

I changed the directory of files and that error message is gone.
When I set reading directory(readDir) to my external hard drive, where all of my raw data is saved, this code perfectly works. However if I set the laptop hard drive, where just part of my raw data is saved, it still gives me back the error message above.

**So I wonder whether the directory of files may cause the error.**

Code that I have been using is following:

```
for filename in os.listdir(readDir):
    filename = os.path.join(readDir, filename)
    for keyword in keywords:
        outFileName = os.path.join(sortDir, keyword)
        outFileName = outFileName+'.csv'

        with open(filename, 'r') as fi, open(outFileName, "a") as fo:
            for line in fi:
```

and **for line in fi** is the location where encoding error message is occurring

Comment: What version of Python are you using and what operating system?  It looks like Python 3 since Python seems to be decoding lines read from the file.  You probably need to specify the encoding of the files read since it doesn't seem to be UTF-8.